# which values belong to two persons

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got these tables:

```
Tabel Instrument
Instrument  Pitch
drums       null
guitar      null
paino       null

Tabel Occupation
Stuknr Instrument
1      guitar
2      piano
2      guitar
3      piano
4      drums
4      guitar

Tabel Music
Stuknr ComposerID
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2

Tabel Composer
ComposerID ComposerName
1          Test1
2          Test2
```

Now i need a query thats:
Which instrument are founds in both music of the composers

my attempt:

```
SELECT I.instrumentnaam
FROM Instrument I 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
          FROM Bezettingsregel B
          WHERE B.instrumentnaam = I.instrumentnaam
          AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                     FROM Stuk S
                     WHERE S.stuknr = B.stuknr
                     AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                                FROM Componist C
                                WHERE C.componistId = S.componistId AND C.naam = 'Karl Schumann' OR  C.naam = 'Thom Guidi')))
```

But this show all instruments for both composer, i want only the instruments that both composer use.

Thanx for help!

Comment: please post output also

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: provide the Output data so that we can answer more efficiently

Comment: Tip: check out GROUP BY, HAVING and COUNT DISTINCT.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: As I said, do a join. GROUP BY its result. Use HAVING to return only the instruments with two different composers.

Comment: @jarlh, now i got this but still don't work.

    SELECT B.instrumentnaam
    FROM Instrument I inner join Bezettingsregel B on I.instrumentnaam         = B.instrumentnaam inner join Stuk S ON B.stuknr = S.stuknr  
inner join Componist C ON S.componistId = C.componistId
GROUP BY C.naam, B.instrumentnaam

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.Instrument
FROM Instrument AS i
JOIN Occupation AS o ON i.Instrument = o.Instrument
JOIN Music AS m ON o.Stuknr = m.Stuknr
JOIN Composer AS c ON m.ComposerID = c.ComposerID
GROUP BY i.Instrument
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.ComposerID) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                       FROM Composer)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7257c5/2)

Comment: Thanx, this works now for only two composers but if the table composer become bigger it won't work anymore right?

Comment: @Yakalent The query returns all instruments common to *all* the composers existent in the `Composer` table. The actual count of the composers shouldn't make any difference to the result of the query.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your requirement

```
select distinct Instrument from #Composer a inner join #music b
on a.ComposerID = b.ComposerID inner join #inst c on b.Stuknr = c.Stuknr 
group by Instrument,ComposerName having count(Instrument)>1
```